# ¿Cómo crear un servicio genérico de HTTP para Angular 8?

Tags: vscode, angular8

Estoy tratando de crear un *servicio genérico* en *Angular* que se encargue de la comunicación con mi *WebApi*, el cual está de la siguiente manera:

```
export class ResourcesServiceApi<T> {

  constructor(
    protected http: HttpClient,
    protected base: string
  ) {}

  findAll(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.http.get<T[]>(this.base);
  }
}
```

Y el constructor del servicio intermedio con el que deseo invocar el servicio genérico lo tengo así:

```
export class AuthService extends ResourcesService<InboxModel> {
  loggedIn = true;
  inbox: InboxModel[];

  constructor(private router: Router, protected http: HttpClient) {
    super(http, 'http://localhost:57929/api/Data/GetInbox?Ban=ALL');
    this.findAll();
  }
}
```

De esa forma no consigo que me retorne los datos, ya que si asigno `this.findAll()` a un arreglo del tipo `InboxModel` no me retorna nada.

De igual forma traté de instanciar la clase del método genérico así:

```
public consultarData() {
    const service = new ResourcesService<InboxModel>(this.http, 'http://localhost:57929/api/Data/GetInbox?Ban=ALL');
    console.log(service.findAll());
}
```

Pero tampoco consigo que me traiga la información, es más, ni siquiera me está haciendo el llamado a la *WebApi*, pero no salta ningún error ni de compilación, ni en la consola de *Chrome*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el método

```
findAll(): Observable<T[]> {
  return this.http.get<T[]>(this.base);
}
```

este método devuelve un `Observable<T[]>`. Por tanto, tienes que suscribirte a él para obtener datos:

```
public consultarData() {
  const service = new ResourcesService<InboxModel>(
      this.http,
      'http://localhost:57929/api/Data/GetInbox?Ban=ALL')
    .subscribe((data : InboxModel[]) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```